# Does ADAL support the PCL Profile 259?

Tags: azure, portable-class-library, adal

I need to use an Active Directory Client from a PCL library (Profile 259).

I tried to install the ADAL nuget package: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, both the latest stable release 2.19 and the latest pre-release 3.5, but both the packages fails to install, showing the following error message:
*"You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."*

As my understanding, this library should support the Profile 259
Is there any problem with the nuget package, or I'm missing something?

If I remove Silverlight from the supported targets (Profile 111), then the ADAL package gets successfully installed, but of course, I miss the Silverlight support.

Is there any way to install the ADAL nuget package in a PCL library which target Profile 259?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I've been wondering why it lists win 8.1 phones if it doesn't support them. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Profile 259 targets

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8

but ADAL does NOT support Windows Phone Silverlight 8 in any version, as it uses the WAB - only available on Windows 8.x and Windows Phone 8.1. Hence, ADAL won't support Profile 259 either.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... 
I've seen it supports the v8.1 of Windows Phone Silverlight :(

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I've been wondering why it lists win 8.1 phones if it doesn't support them. Any workaround?

Comment: Mane, ADAL v2.x DIES support winphone 8.1. The issue in the thread was about winphone 8.